# Laravel 5.3 API not fetching data while using JavaScript on server

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

**Routes:** \routes\web.php

```
Route::get('api/get-market-list','MemberTradesController@getMarketList');

Route::get('api/get-market-list1','MemberTradesController@getMarketListtest');
```

**Controller** MemberTradesController

There're two function, **getMarketListtest**(just for testing on server) and **getMarketList** (this is for Request $request because, i have used it in dependent select box)

```
    public function getMarketListtest(){
        $markets = DB::table("markets")
            ->pluck("market","id");
        return response() -> json($markets);
    }

    public function getMarketList(Request $request){
        $markets = DB::table("markets")
            ->where("exchange_id", $request->exchange_id)
            ->pluck("market","id");
        return response() -> json($markets);
    }
```

**Java scripts :**

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#exchange').change(function(){
        var exchangeID = $(this).val();
        if(exchangeID){
            $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:"{{url('api/get-market-list')}}?exchange_id="+exchangeID,
                success:function(res){
                    if(res){
                        $("#market").empty();
                        $("#market").append('<option>Select</option>');
                        $.each(res,function(key,value){
                            $("#market").append('<option value="'+key+'">'+value+'</option>');
                        });

                    }else{
                        $("#market").empty();
                    }
                }
            });
        }else{
            $("#market").empty();
            $("#symbol").empty();
        }
    });

</script>
```

View:

```js
    <title>Laravel 5 - Dynamic autocomplete search using select2 JS Ajax</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

```html
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST', 'action'=> 'MemberTradesController@store']) !!}


  <div class="form-group col-sm-5">
            {!! Form::label('exchange_id', 'Exchanges:') !!}
            {!! Form::select('exchange_id', [''=>'Choose Options'] + $exchanges , null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>'exchange'])!!}
        </div>

 <div class="form-group col-sm-5">
                {!! Form::label('market_id', 'Markets:') !!}
                {!! Form::select('market_id', [''=>'Choose Options'] , null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>'market'])!!}
            </div>
            
 {!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Screenshot of TABLE:**

[**Screenshot of TABLE:**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/asUkp.jpg)

For Function two [Link for API result : api/get-market-list](http://www.yourtradelog.com/api/get-market-list?exchange_id=1)

**Important information :**

- when i'm using this in my localhost, its give me result.
- first api **getMarketListtest()** is working, because there is not having : (Request $request)

[Error Log of laravel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ukda8.jpg)

**[Changed code as per you function ]**[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZkYJ.png)

Comment: Your urls and html IDs don't match anywhere. Is this because you skipped some copy-paste or might it be the root of your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$request->input('exchange_id');` instead of `$request->exchange_id`

Just try to replace this function.

```
public function getMarketList(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request){
    $exchange_id = $request->input('exchange_id');
    if(!empty($exchange_id)){
    \Log::info('This is working.');
    }
    $markets = DB::table("markets")
        ->where('exchange_id', $exchange_id)
        ->pluck("market","id");
    return response()->json($markets);
}
```

Please comment if any errors.

Comment: This is not working in server but i have also pasted your  function in my localhost, it worked but...my older function also working in localhost... i am getting problem in server ... i am checking trough url is :** http://www.yourtradelog.com/api/get-market-list?exchange_id=+1   **  can you check is this ok url? and I also tired by without +    Can I get your contact detail? I really want to solve this and i can pay for this also

Comment: Check my updated answer. On server you can check by print log in console log. Please change this code in server and check it's creating log or not.

Comment: I have also updated result both, localhost and server url in screeshoot 4... its worked in localhost but not in server. i have also updated laravel log.

Comment: @rajyaguruKamleshbhai I have noticed that `http://www.yourtradelog.com/api/get-market-list` this api is also returning nothing.

Comment: ohh! sorry.. it was returning... let me complete it first ... i am sorry

Comment: See this route: http://www.yourtradelog.com/api/get-market-list1 this is working   **ROUTE** : api/get-market-list1

Comment: Last try i can give you is try `\Illuminate\Http\Request $request` use this instance. I have updated my answer

Comment: You have tired so much and thanks for it. its till not working if you say, i can give my laptop access and also server access but i want to solve this... I dont mind you charge for it.

Comment: I am not too familiar with server sorry but try this command on server in your laravel public folder `php artisan cache:clear` may be it will help.

Comment: I have also done php artisan cache:clear but till not working.

Comment: What does the `$request` variable contain? @rajyaguruKamleshbhai

Comment: @coleander its contain exchange_id i added its textfiled in view

Comment: i have updated javascript can you check it? @ChiragPatel